# how to store php code into a file on remote server?

Tags: php

```
textarea.on('input', function(){
    //ajax code to store the content into a file on remote server
});
```

on php side I'm using `file_put_contents($path, $content);`

problem - if some code or function name, for example `session_start` is a part of textarea content - remote server is blocked, i.e. my ip address is blocked.

apparently, this is treated as an attack

how to avoid this?

Comment: Is there a WAF or something in place? Do you have control of both servers?

Comment: @user3783243 - what is WAF?

Comment: Web application firewall, I've had to disable some rules on my AWS one because they contained strings AWS considered malicious but weren't (e.g. non URL encoded forward slashes in query string)

Comment: @user3783243 - yes, there is such a firewall, and I turned it off on cPanel - but I'm afraid this is not a clever solution regarding security

Comment: Well, with AWS they have rules. Is yours online on/off or can you control what rules are on? Also, AWS has whitelisting rules, so for example I could allow my IP to still send in these requests. This likely is not something you can solve with PHP... possibly base64 encode the text area content prior to submitting?

Comment: @user3783243 - I have only on/off options for a specific domain. Is there a possibility for a real atack if I turn it off? Once again - my only task on server is `file_put_contents($path, $content);` Also, all the content of textarea here, on this site, full of code examples, is also placed somewhere, how it is done?